# Как узнать, что поток закончил свое выполнение?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть обработка такой ситуации при которой я показываю юзеру сообщение на 6 секунд и мне нужно сразу после показа этого сообщения отправить юзера на другое активити.

Я понимаю что это можно сделать в `AsynTask` но проблема в том, что метод который содержит этот `AsynTask` находится в классе хелпер и используется еще в других местах приложения где не нужно скидывать юзера на другое активити.

Выглядит обработка ошибки в вызывающем классе так

```
} else {
                    CameraHelper.showDialog(getFragmentManager(), context);
                    goToMain();
                }
```

и вот метод `showDialog()` из `CameraHelper` :

```
public static void showDialog(final FragmentManager fragmentManager, final Context context) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        private MyDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog = MyDialog.newInstance(R.layout.dialog_connection);
            dialog.show(fragmentManager, "dialog");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(6);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }.execute();
}
```

И проблема в том, что когда вызывающий класс вызывает метод с показом диалога то диалог не успевает открыться как срабатывает метод `goToMain()` и юзера сразу отправляет на следующее активити.

Как сделать чтоб метод `goToMain()` дожидался выполнения `CameraHelper.showDialog();` ??

Comment: onPostExecute же?

Comment: @TheNorthon не понял...

Comment: плохо сперва прочитал вопрос, ниже Андроид Андроид дал хороший ответ, демонстрирующий Наблюдателя (Observer pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создайте класс колбэк для вашего метода, типа

```
public class CallBackDialog {

    public void onSuccess() {
    }

}
```

В тело метода третьим параметром передавайте его

```
showDialog(final FragmentManager fragmentManager, final Context context, final CallBackDialog callBackDialog)
```

в `onPostExecute` верните его в активити

```
       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            dialog.dismiss();
            callBackDialog.onSuccess();
        }
```

В активити вызываем и ждем его окончания, чтобы запустить другой метод

```
CameraHelper.showDialog(getFragmentManager(), context, new CallBackDialog() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
              goToMain();
               }
            });
```

Comment: Вау!)) Я понял как это работает наконец то)) Я часто встречал такие конструкции,. а сейчас прям понял как это работет)) ничего сложно, но очень круто. Спасибо!